# jQuery: How would I get a div to expand to a height and add text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I've got a homepage with a container-div below the nav that I'm attempting to expand to a set height and add specific text inside of the container-div.

On top of that I'm only wanting it to do this when I'm navigating from the home page only.

Any jQuery magic that would help me do this?

Thanks!

Here is the before at the home page
[image: Before]

Here is the after at a different page that was clicked on on the home and loaded.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some example code? It's difficult to tell exactly what you're going for here.

Comment: I've updated the question with a couple of screen-shots of what I'm trying to complete.

Comment: I think the answers here are pretty close. How about starting off with possibly a jquery function that will load when it isn't on a certain page? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $('.container').css('height', '50px').text('Bye bye!');
}
```

You might also want to try nesting another element inside the container to prevent you manually specifying the container height. You could then minimize your JavaScript/CSS down to:

```
$('.container .child').show();

.child {
   height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#container-div').animate({
    height: '100px' // your target fixed height.
}, 'fast').html('specific text');
```

Where your container div has the ID `container-div`. If you don't want a transition, you can use `.css()`.

```
$('#container-div').css('height', '100px').html('specific text');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with CSS3:
    Create a CSS3 animation:

```
/* Create predefined animation using keyframes */
@keyframes appear { 0% { height: 0px; } 100% { height: 100%; } }
@-o-keyframes appear { 0% { height: 0px; } 100% { height: 100%; } }
@-moz-keyframes appear { 0% { height: 0px; } 100% { height: 100%; } }
@-webkit-keyframes appear { 0% { height: 0px; } 100% { height: 100%; } }

/* will effect in children with less then 150px to slide to this height */
div { min-height: 150px; } 
/* Div is larger then 150px? It will just animate to its required height */
div:hover > div { 
  -webkit-animation: drop 1s 1 linear;
  -moz-animation: drop 1s 1 linear;
  -o-animation: drop 1s 1 linear;
  animation: drop 1s 1 linear;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

[Example working](http://jsfiddle.net/7eENn/)